how to plot Yearly and Monthly Data on the Same graph in python
I’m facing a problem in plotting datasets with different frequencies on the same Matplotlib plot. Specifically, I have yearly chlorophyll-a concentration data and monthly MEI.V2 data, both spanning from 1998 to 2021. How can I effectively visualize them on the same plot?
Here’s some dummy data to for the problem:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Generate yearly chlorophyll-a concentration data
np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range(start='1998-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='Y')
chlorophyll_data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=len(dates))
chlorophyll_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Chlorophyll-a': chlorophyll_data})

# Generate monthly MEI.V2 data
monthly_dates = pd.date_range(start='1998-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='M')
mei_data = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=2, size=len(monthly_dates))
mei_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': monthly_dates, 'MEI.V2': mei_data})

My attempt at plotting both datasets is as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# Primary y-axis (left)
ax1.plot(chlorophyll_df.index, chlorophyll_df['Chlorophyll-a'], marker='P', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax1.set_ylabel('Chlorophyll-a concentration [mg $m^{-3}$]')
ax1.legend(ncol=4, loc='upper center')

# Explicitly set the x-axis range
plt.xlim(1998, 2021)

# Secondary y-axis (right)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(mei_df.index, mei_df['MEI.V2'], color='red', linestyle='-')
ax2.set_ylabel('MEI.V2', color='red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')

# Plot formatting
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

However, I encounter an issue that is something weird.
See the image it is coming:

Desired Outcome:
I aim to visualize both datasets on the same plot, with chlorophyll-a concentration on the primary y-axis and MEI.V2 on the secondary y-axis. It's crucial that the monthly MEI.V2 data aligns with the corresponding years on the x-axis.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this effectively.
Thank you!

Get rid of plt.xlim(1998, 2021), then use chlorophyll_df['Date]andmei_df['Date']instead ofchlorophyll_df.indexandmei_df.index`: https://i.sstatic.net/TaFhs.png

You're trying to plot datetime data while giving integers. The integers are accepted in place of dates because the x-axis is really in ordinal time (I believe microseconds are the default). The line plt.xlim(1998, 2021) is, I believe, telling the computer to plot between some microseconds in 1970

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator

# Generate yearly chlorophyll-a concentration data
np.random.seed(1)
dates = pd.date_range(start='1998-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='YE')
chlorophyll_data = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=len(dates))
chlorophyll_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Chlorophyll-a': 
chlorophyll_data})

# Generate monthly MEI.V2 data
monthly_dates = pd.date_range(start='1998-01-01', end='2021-12-31', 
freq='ME')
mei_data = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=2, size=len(monthly_dates))
mei_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': monthly_dates, 'MEI.V2': mei_data})

# Resample monthly MEI.V2 data to yearly averages
mei_yearly_df = mei_df.resample('YE', on='Date').mean()

# Plot both datasets
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# Primary y-axis (left) for chlorophyll-a concentration
ax1.plot(chlorophyll_df['Date'], chlorophyll_df['Chlorophyll-a'], 
marker='P', linestyle='-', label='Chlorophyll-a concentration')
ax1.set_ylabel('Chlorophyll-a concentration [mg $m^{-3}$]', color = 
'blue')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')

# Secondary y-axis (right) for MEI.V2
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(mei_yearly_df.index, mei_yearly_df['MEI.V2'], color='red', 
linestyle='-', label='MEI.V2')
ax2.set_ylabel('MEI.V2', color='red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')

# Set x-axis ticks to match the years
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(len(dates.year)))

# Set x-axis ticks to show only the year
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())

# Plot formatting
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Chlorophyll-a Concentration and MEI.V2')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
